# Flags disputed on a link-only answer

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, disputed-flags

I recently flagged the following answer as being of low-quality, and both flags were disputed.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43623198/1415724

The flags and responses are as follows:

1) *very low quality – Fred -ii- 12 hours ago
 Response: disputed*

2) (for moderation): *I flagged this question yesterday as being of low-quality since it only contains linked only resources. This is a known topic [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/)
 Response:  declined - If you remove the links, the answer is still (minimally) viable, which is how it was reviewed: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15950023 - disputed*

What is up with that? That totally goes against what has already been posted on meta about this:

- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

This is a known problem with reviewers sending the wrong message by not paying attention or upholding what with Stack deems as being of low-quality.

So, has the playing field now just suddenly changed? Has Stack and its reviewers/moderators now turned over a new leaf without telling us and that we are to continually support link-only answers?

That's the message I am getting out of this and I don't support, I protest it.

---

**Edit:**

If the answer in question had contained a better descriptive method, then I'd of supported it and not have said/done anything.

Say for example and I'll use this analogy:

**Chef:** *"Ok, cut up those potatoes for me."*

**Apprentice cook:** *"So, how do you want me to cut them and in how big a piece and where should I put them after, in a bowl or just anywhere?"*

So, IMHO, it should have at *least* contained something like:

> *"Place the following inside `<head></head>` of your document and you should be good to go. Stylesheet references (should) go inside (valid HTML) markup tags."*

Many don't know HTML or have even gone through an HTML 101 course. They'll just drop code in a file wherever it fits (believe me, I've seen this often and some pretty bad ones also).

Well, HTML doesn't work that way and we don't know the OP's knowledge and this for any future visitor to the question/answer who may also not know.

---

**Edit #2:**

Comments pulled from under the question (in question):

*"This is not a link only answer. Even without the hyperlink markup, this is a valid answer. You need to include those files, wherever you may get them from for bootstrap to work properly. The links themselves are just useful additions to this answer. – Tiny Giant 2 hours ago"*

*"@Alon for sure, bootstrap will throw an error because jQuery is not included, but bootstrap's JavaScript isn't necessary (AFAIK) to make the tabs feature work. Again, this is an attempted answer. Regardless of how much you dislike the answer or despise the person for even thinking of trying to be helpful, it is an attempted answer and should not be flagged. If you think this answer is incorrect or not useful, feel free to downvote, but this answer should not be flagged, nor should it be deleted through review or by a moderator. – Tiny Giant 1 hour ago"*

and one of my replies:

*"This is not a link only answer" - It's not only a link only answer, it's also incomplete. @TinyGiant Edit: "nor should it be deleted through review or by a moderator." - Nor should it be edited by anyone else but the answerer themselves. – Fred -ii- 13 mins ago"*

IMHO, an incomplete answer not containing (all) the essential parts means just that; of low quality.

To merely say/contain: *"include bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js"* - (to me), is interpreted as: *"This is all you need"*, or *"Include this and then figure out the rest for yourself"*; which is being unclear.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a traditional link-only answer. The answer isn't hidden behind the links, but the links themselves are the answer. I.e. you're supposed to put these links into a `<script src="...">`. But since the answer doesn't explain that, it's low quality nonetheless.

Comment: @Floern But isn't it up to the OP of that answer to provide all the details? It can easily be a comment in its current state - It suggest laziness and being the [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: @AlonEitan It would be incorrect as a comment. It's an answer to the question. It's a poor answer, it needs updated to explain itself, but it _is_ an answer. It also _can_ be edited to fix its problem, so it's not "very low quality" either. I see nothing wrong with how the flags were handled.

Comment: @Floern Agreed. The answer is of low-quality in more ways than one. How many times I've seen answers like that getting many negative votes but not that one; I just don't get it.

Comment: @AlonEitan yes, it's a bad answer. You can take a look at the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43623225/559745) to see how it should have been done correctly.

Comment: I disagree this is a link only answer. It reads fine stripping the links. It is a **bad**, lazy, incomplete answer anyway. Should be downvoted.

Comment: @AlonEitan *"It can easily be a comment in its current state - It suggest laziness..."* - Yep and quite a few times I've seen what should have been a comment. If however they would have posted it as a comment and that the OP had invited them to post their comment as an answer, and given more information than just simply "include this...", then that would have made for a better answer and is often seen as being acceptable; this wasnt' the case here.

Comment: The response of *"if you remove the links, the answer is still (minimally) viable)"* puzzles me some. While technically correct it would seem more of a comment / even lower quality than it is, no? There must be a really fine line for link only answers. For example: [this answer on an older question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10562353/1011527) would certainly be killed today.

Comment: @Floern Exactly, and that type of answers is what we're looking for on SO. So I think where compromising the quality of the answers by letting it slip

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm puzzled as well, if not baffled.

Comment: It can't be a link only answer then the contents of the link are not the answer to the question, but the resource to be used. The answer is to _include_ the linked files, as the answer states. Again, still believe it's a bad, downvotable answer, but no a VLQ one.

Comment: Even though I agree with Kendra that this answer doesn't match the guidelines for "link-only", it still shows that it is a bit of nonsense to even discuss about such answers. Stack Overflow is supposed to provide quality content and that we now discuss if an answer is crap (downvote+comment) or complete crap (flag+downvote+comment) seems very disappointing.

Comment: *IMHO, an incomplete answer not containing (all) the essential parts means just that; of low quality.* Exactly.  It is low quality, not very low quality or not an answer.  A low quality answer can be down voted and manually deleted.  It should not be flagged.

Comment: @Tom No, it's not a degree of difference in quality.  If a post is a *bad answer* then you downvote it.  If a post *isn't even an answer at all* (which is something that can unambiguously be determined by someone who's not knowledgeable about the subject matter) *then* it merits deletion.  Flags aren't "super downvotes" for posts that you think are "even worse" than other bad answers.

Comment: @NathanOliver Stack didn't include just a "low quality" option ;-) so where do we draw the line between flagging or not flagging?

Comment: low quality == bad answer, can be improved improvement.  very low quality == bad answer/not an answer, cant be improved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, SE *does* have a "low quality" option.  It's the downvote button.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, bad (incomplete) answers need to be downvoted, not upvoted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I never said they should.  I just said they should not be flagged.  It is perfectly acceptable to down vote and delete vote low quality/bad answer

Comment: @Servy Sure, downvote; then what? Keep on sending the wrong message by someone upvoting it and in its own right, stating that that is all they need? Sorry, but that never has, and never will wash in my books.

Comment: @NathanOliver (and here) I thought I had a say/privilege to flag as (very) low-quality. I honestly don't know where to throw myself with these flagging options anymore.

Comment: @Servy *"Flags aren't "super downvotes" for posts that you think are "even worse" than other bad answers"* Don't put words in my mouth, thank you.

Comment: Nope.  Your rep level doesn't give you more latitude on what to flag.  Instead you use your delete votes that your high rep has given you to clean out low quality content.

Comment: @Fred-ii- And you think getting your flags declined, or even getting yourself flag banned, because you're intentionally abusing the flagging system to flag posts *that you know full well don't merit flagging* because you don't think that downvotes are "severe" enough is going to have a better result?  Yes, some people upvote bad posts; it's sucks, and it makes me sad.  That doesn't mean that you should cast flags that you know full well are just going to get declined, and then act upset when they're declined.

Comment: @Tom I'm not putting words in your mouth.

Comment: @NathanOliver *"Instead you use your delete votes that your high rep has given you to clean out low quality content"* - Delete votes only apppear on a minimum of -1; so even with my downvote at the time, rounded it off to `0` so I couldn't do anything about it.

Comment: @Servy *"because you're intentionally abusing the flagging system to flag post"* - Please don't say I'm doing this intentionally, you're saying I'm the bad guy here who likes to do bad things; I resent that. I honestly thought that by flagging as low quality (oh, excuse me, *very* low quality) that I was within my bounds to do so; I obviously have been steered wrong.

Comment: @Servy *"and then act upset when they're declined"* - believe me, I'm not upset or jumping up and down like a kid who didn't get his candy or whatever else kids cry about these days; I'm just completely baffled and slightly annoyed, sure. This is on a **"principles"** and a "need to know" basis.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not much you can go with that.  Best you can do is leave a comment as to why you feel it is a bad answer and hope others agree.  If they do then hopefully, over time, it will reach a deleteable state and we can get rid of it.  I often do this myself where I'll favorite/bookmark things and then come back a week or two later and see where it is at.

Comment: Re partial answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers suggests those are fine; https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72445/274165 suggests making them CW. I don't believe there is any guidance to *delete* partial answers, unless they are clearly strictly inferior to answers posted much earlier.

Comment: Looks like someone flagged all of the comments there and everything was deleted, so now nothing makes sense.

Answer (score 19):

That answer is not "link only" by the ["Castle" guidance.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

The answer, without link markup (as it is supposed to be reviewed for link-onlyness):

> include bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js

**Is that a poor answer?** Certainly. It needs to explain itself a bit more, to be really useful to other users.

**Does it answer the question?** Yes, as can be seen in the accepted answer. The answer in question is done poorly, but it does answer the question.

**Can it be salvaged through editing?** Most certainly! Therefore, it is *also* not "very low quality."

Therefore, this answer is a low quality answer, but it is not a *very* low quality answer, so your first flag was incorrect. Likewise, the mods were correct that the answer does not merit *immediate* deletion according to the guidelines.

Now, it does merit downvotes. Should it be deleted eventually? Probably, if it's not edited by the author, but it's not 100% unsalvagable trash that has to go right this instance. That's what the "very low quality" flag is for, trash that is so smelly it has to go to the dumpster immediately.

**But doesn't it work as a comment?** No. Comments are for clarification of posts, *not* for answers. Technically, yes, it would be able to be posted as a comment, but it would not be what comments are for.

Comment: The first answer in the Castle post has this: *"Answers need to have sufficient information to **understand the answer**. The answer should be described in a reasonable level of detail and / or include a minimal example of the answer."*

Comment: It's annoying because you're probably right. But that answer is for the cheap thrill of quick reputation (As far as I see it anyway)

Comment: The first answer in the Castle post is not the guidance linked to. The _question_ is the guidance. That the first answer disagrees with the community moderator who posted it does not make the first answer the guidance. @JayBlanchard Also note that there is a _lot_ of disagreement about that statement in the comments of the answer you mention.

Comment: Well... I'm kind of on the (good side of the) fence with what you're saying but yeah... I agree. The answer should have been better written, and that is part of what my flag was about; poor quality as far as the answer was and the linked references. Stack encourages people to do that and we also try to help them. Many times they just ignore us or give us hell. This is often a double-edged sword that we need to bear and a "darned if we/I do, darned if we/I don't" type of thing. (+1).

Comment: I realize that the first answer is not the guidance, but the statement I highlighted makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @JayBlanchard And not even all of the other high rep/long time users on that post agree with that statement. Feel free to follow that statement if you wish, but do keep in mind that people following the guidance and not that user's thoughts on it will disagree when handling your flags.

Comment: *"That answer is not "link only" by the "Castle" guidance."* - @Kendra I tend to disagree here. From the [most upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226142/231583) and I quote: *"When an answer says:... - You probably want a FileOutputStream [LINK] ... I don't think that is an answer. It still needs to make clear HOW the FileOutputStream could be applied in the solution."*  - I feel is what the answer in question falls under; but do correct me if I'm wrong here ;-)

Comment: *"But doesn't it work as a comment? No. Comments are for clarification of posts, not for answers. Technically, yes, it would be able to be posted as a comment, but it would not be what comments are for."* - Technically, yes; agreed. Yet if a lower rep member were to post a comment and the OP invites them to post it as an answer, I will support it but "only" if it is modified to be a better (explained) answer, I'm all for that. I myself will post an answer based on a comment I placed that solved a question, yet more often than none I will post it as a community wiki.

Comment: @Fred-ii- See my comments to Jay concerning the answer you're referencing. As for comments, I stand by what I've already said. It's an answer. A ***poor*** answer, but an answer. Answers do not belong in the comments, just as comments do not belong in the answers.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is perfectly valid complete answer "include bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js".

Anyone with minimal knowledge of HTML should be able to understand it and create solution based on given information.

Is it the best ever answer - no. Should it be improved - it could, but it is not  beneficial for the site - there are plenty of existing https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+include+bootstrap answers. It definitely can be downvoted in comparison to hundreds of other posts explaining how to do so. If that would be unique post (like first ever question about the topic) I would upvote it.

Should the other answer be upvoted for reasonable content or both downvoted for posting yet another "how to include bootstrap"? Personally I don't feel upvoting duplication of content as a good thing...

Proper action would be to VTC question as duplicate.

Comment: _Can it be understood by someone with minimal knowledge of HTML - definitely yes._ - Agree. But take a look at the question, it's pretty obvious they don't have any knowledge

Comment: *"Anyone with minimal knowledge of HTML should be able to understand it and create solution based on given information."* - Funny you should write that, I was just about to make an edit in relation to that. Give me a minute... I'm almost done typing it up. Edit: (new edit) done @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: _"Should it be improved - it could, but it is not beneficial for the site"_ I would argue that it _does_ need improved, for the benefit of future users. If someone is having this issue and comes to the site for an answer, they shouldn't have to look elsewhere to figure out how to implement the answer they've found. Someone not familiar with HTML could be having to stand in for an ill coworker to make this fix. The answer is still correct, it's just not insanely helpful unless you already know what you're doing. (I would argue you're less likely to need the answer if you understand it...)

Comment: @AlonEitan lack of knowledge on OP part is not criteria for correctness of an answer to my understanding...

Comment: @Kendra I see absolutely *no value* in improving that particular post - there is already decent answer to the same question as well as tons of duplicates. If that would be only answer - sure (also I personally would close as duplicate, or maybe as Alon Eitan hinted - "too broad" as OP potentially need small book on "creating HTML with CSS and JavaScript")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Of course, and I agree about that, but when I typed "how to include b" google autosuggest "how to include bootstrap in html" - What's wrong with some people?? Nothing rewording in only asking the most basic and, excuse me, _pathetic_ question there is. One should do some research before asking for heaven's sake

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You should evaluate the usefulness of posts without worrying about other answers, or the answers in general if evaluating the question. What if the other answer was removed tomorrow, for a perfectly valid reason that keeps it from being undeleted? Therefore, yes, that answer should be improved if you aren't comparing it to other answers. If you evaluate a post based on the posts around it, a decent answer could end up looking like total crap.

Comment: But anyway, I've just VTC for "why dis code not workz" - They should Google it next time

Comment: @Alon well that is disingenuous, the MCVE is included, as well as a clear problem description. I seriously don't understand what the obsession with closing this question is. Yeah, it's not a good question, but it isn't off-topic and we don't need to go all hate-mode on it. If anything, find a good duplicate to close it against.